# How to extract exponents and modulus from SSH-RSA key files

Tags: ssh, rsa

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4253.html
::http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4251.html

Does anyone know the SSH key file format?

!! UPDATE
!! The base64 function I was using doesn't work.  After running the key file through a different function (mozilla's built in atob()) the data fit into the specifications listed above.

I have rsa key files created with puttygen, but I must be missing something critical.  Here is the hex of the public section:

```
00 00 00 07 73 73 68 2d 72 73 61 00 00 00 01 25
00 00 00 10 1c 1c 57 3f 4f 58 63 69 38 ad 19 35
b5 28 3d 78 53 35 53 6c 15 0e 69 23 ac 17 14 84
21 29 13 07 36 62 90 26 37 93 73 17 28 b8 ce 95
c3 11 24 21 61 b7 82 d9 04 42 97 f8 27 c3 44 06
46 ca e8 a3 a3 34 d7 3c c3 95 13 dd 16 1b 2c 29
7c 35 19 5f c2 7a 17 d5 14 0d 26 36 27 18 71 67
8d 9c 5b c4 7d
```

first 4 bytes are UINT 7, the number of bytes inthe following string "ssh-rsa" but the format stops making sense after that.  It SHOULD be followed by two MPINT but they lengths don't add up for the 3rd value.

Thanks!

Comment: PuTTYgen can load and save in several file formats and it's not clear to me which one you mean, but you do know that PuTTY is open source, right?  You could just go read [putty/sshpubk.c](http://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty/sshpubk.c?view=markup).

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for.  The function that creates the BLOB in question is rsa2_public_blob() at http://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty/sshrsa.c?revision=8202&view=markup
unfortunately, the bytes above, generated with PuTTY are not to that spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in ASN.1 syntax. You should be able to use an ASN.1 parser along with the specs for the file contents to decipher it.

Comment: OpenSSL's [asn1parse](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/asn1parse.html) utility has saved my bacon a few times.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but I already have the specs, they're just not right.  I probably need to look at public key BLOBs from other sources as well, but the blob in the keyfile created in putty's PPK format is not to spec.